# How can I write Unit Tests for classes that run until Keyboard Interrupt and don't return anything?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-watchdog

I am working on a Python service that monitors a directory in the filesystem. When it sees that a file has been created or moved there, it sends the path of the file into a Kafka queue. I have the service working exactly like I need it to, but my problem is that I am supposed to have at least 90% coverage with unit tests. I am relatively new to Python, and I haven't ever used unit testing in any language before, so I feel really out of my depth. I just can't wrap my head around how I would go about testing these classes.

This is the class that monitors the file system, I'm using the [watchdog](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/) library.

I added the `handler=FileHandler` parameter to **init** because I figured I could use that to pass the class a fake handler I could use for the tests, but that feels like it's unnecessarily complicated.

```py
class FileSystemMonitor:

    def __init__(self, target_path, kafka_queue, handler=FileHandler):
        self.path = target_path
        self.queue = kafka_queue
        self.handler = handler(self.queue)

    def start(self):
        observer = Observer()
        observer.schedule(self.handler, self.path, recursive=True)
        observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            observer.stop()
        observer.join()

def parse_args():
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    queue = sys.argv[2] if len(sys.argv) > 2 else 'default'
    return path, queue

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path, queue = parse_args()
    monitor = FileSystemMonitor(path, queue)
    monitor.start()
```

---

This is the class I made which handles the events thrown by the monitor, and passes the path to the Kafka Queue.

```py
class FileHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):

    def __init__(self, queue):
        super(FileHandler, self).__init__(ignore_patterns=["*/.DS_Store"], ignore_directories=True)
        self.queue = queue

    def on_any_event(self, event):
        super(FileHandler, self).on_any_event(event)
        #print(event, self.queue)
        result = kafkaProducer.send_msg(self.queue, event.src_path, event.event_type)
        print("Handler:", result)
        return result
```

I've written some tests for the kafkaProducer class, and I didn't have a very hard time with that, because it actually returns a value that I could test.

FileSystemMonitor runs infinitely and just waits for a keyboard interrupt, and when it does end, it doesn't return anything, so how do I write the unit tests for it?

As for the FileHandler class it depends on events being triggered by the monitor class, so how would I isolate the Handler class to test it?

Comment: Just write more additional unused and trivial-to-test code, until coverage reaches 90%.

Comment: I like the way you think XD but I feel like that might not go over too well at my code reviews.

Comment: Is there some behavior that you actually want to test or you just want to reach the coverage threshold?

Comment: Regardig `FileHandler ` your test should be able to instantiate it and call `on_any_event()` with any event they want. You don't need a `FileSystemMonitor` for that.

Comment: @Goyo I want to reach the coverage threshold,  but I don't want to take a bunch of shortcuts to do so.

Comment: @Goyo in reference to the FileHandler, Thank you. I got tests written for it that I'm happy with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FileSystemMonitor.start` is very hard to test since it blocks until an external event happens but the test can't easily make the event happen because of the block. I guess you could do some trick with multithreading or multiprocessing or maybe just a timer, but this would add some indeterminism to your test which I don't like.

A more explicit approach is allow the caller to specify what happens inside the `while` loop so that an exception can be raised in the test while `time.sleep` will be called in the production code.

```
class FileSystemMonitor:
    def __init__(self, target_path, kafka_queue, handler=FileHandler):
        self.path = target_path
        self.queue = kafka_queue
        self.handler = handler(self.queue)

    def start(self, loop_action):
        observer = Observer()
        observer.schedule(self.handler, self.path, recursive=True)
        observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                loop_action()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            observer.stop()
        observer.join()
```

This is what your test would look like:

```
def fake_loop_action():
    raise KeyboardInterrupt

def test_FileSystemMonitor():
    # Initialize target_path, kafka_queue and handler here.
    # You might want to use test doubles.
    monitor = FileSystemMonitor(target_path, kafka_queue, handler)
    monitor.start(loop_action=fake_loop_action)
```

And in the production code you would use `time.sleep` instead. You can even specify the delay in the call now.

```
monitor.start(loop_action=lambda: time.sleep(1))
```